# How to use C++ code snippets in Visual Studio 2008 Pro?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, code-snippets

I have prepared C++ code snippet. How to use it in VS2008 Pro?

Answer (score 1):

[this blog](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/gilf/archive/2009/01/17/how-to-write-your-own-code-snippets.aspx) shows how to create and import snippets into the snippet manager.

it's simply just a matter of clicking on Tools --> Code Snippet Manager, and then browsing for what you want to import.

hope this helps.

Comment: The language C++ is not listed in the combobox at the top of the Code Snippets Manager.  In Visual Studio 2005, we had to install "Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 IDE Enhancements" package.  Anybody knows how to have the code snippets working with C++?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Snippet Editor](http://www.codeplex.com/SnippetEditor).

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a way to integrate to the VS code manager in C++, so I started to use jCodeCollector snippet manager.

It's pretty basic, so its really easy to get used to. Pretty sufficient for me :-).

http://alessandro-cocco.blogspot.com/p/jcodecollector_22.html